# Win Service running under LocalService account cannot access environment variables

Tags: windows-service, environment-variables, local-system

I am looking for prove or disprove of my theory. We have windows service which runs under LocalSystem account. the service is calling `msbuild` and builds `csproj` (Visual Studio project) file, which use Environment variable. But its falling as it cant recognize or find that environment variable.

Is there way how I can test or assure that win service running under LocalSystem has access to environment variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your environment variables are changing and you're running the service (as LocalSystem) in Windows Server 2003, XP, or 2000 then you might be running into the case that you need to restart the machine in order for the service manager to reread the environment.  See [**this KB article**](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/821761) for more info.

[**There's a hotfix available**](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/887693) for Windows Server 2003 that will resolve this.

Comment: thanks for tip. Restarting helped. Any idea if the same applies to windows server 2008?

Answer (score 5):

Programs running as SYSTEM (LocalSystem, NT_AUTHORITY\SYSTEM) will have an environment built from the variables specified at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment` and at `HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Environment`. Make sure the variables you want it to "see" are defined in one of those locations and they will be accessible.

Comment: Session Manager\Environment key was lost on reboot?

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying / asking. No-- Windows will not just randomly remove registry values specified at that location. Perhaps you booted a different ControlSet, however. `CurrentControlSet` is a symlink to the booted ControlSet.

Comment: It wasn't really a question of if, more why. After setting that key and rebooting the value was gone.  I assume it's built dynamically from data in other locations. I haven't checked yet  whether adding the value to the `.Default\Environment` key was sufficient to solve that issue, but `HKLM`, while it works at first, appears to not survive a reboot.